# Cannot install MKL on Google Cloud - not enough space

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, intel-mkl

Hope the question won't be too broad, but I'm a beginner with Linux. I set up my first Google Cloud instance according to [this tutorial](http://grantmcdermott.com/2017/05/30/rstudio-server-compute-engine/). I also wanted to install Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL) according to [this instructions](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/mkl4deb). However, while calling

```
apt-get install intel-mkl-64bit-2018.2-046
```

I get:

> Need to get 539 MB of archives.
>   After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>   E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```

but it didn't help. How can I check how much free space left I have on my instance? How can I free up some space to be able to install MKL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df` command to check the general disk usage. If you want to check how much space specific directories took on the instance, use `du [DIRECTORY] -h` (the `-h` parameter makes the result more human readable. For example, you can use something like `sudo du -h --max-depth=1` to show how much space each directory in your root directory is taking so you can decide where to delete stuff from.

Besides the above manual check, you can also try `apt-get autoremove`, it will scan and remove old and unused dependencies installed before.